# Is there a way to have multiple data-paramname and data-paramvalue in javascript?

Tags: javascript

In my code I have:

```
    <input type=button data-paramname="firstname" data-paramvalue="Joe" data-paramname="lastname" data-paramvalue="Smith" value="Test Button">
```

But the 2nd data-paramname is ignored, and when I inspect the element in the browser it only sees:

```
<input type=button data-paramname="firstname" data-paramvalue="Joe" value="Test Button">
```

What is the best work around for this, to have 2 params for a particular button?

Comment: why not make it `data-paramname` and `data-param2name` if you have two params?

Comment: If you have an arbitrary number of *parameters* you could always encode them with JSON, reducing them to one string.

Answer (score 2):

No attributes should not be duplicated. This is poor practice and even if it does work in some browsers you will probably have issues in others. Either use different attributes or put the values in the same attribute and comma delimit them.

Comment: When I do that it shows in the browser code, but the variable is not passed on to the application.

Comment: How does it know to associate data-paramname  with data-paramvalue?

When I try
data-param2name
or
data2-paramname 
the value is coming in blank for data-param2value or data2-paramvalue.